JEDIS, Query nested tables, how?
I have JSON structure in REDIS that looks something like:
{
  "name": "value"
  "subtable": {
    "sub1":{
      "subtime": 123456
    }
    "sub2":{
      "subtime": 999999
    }
  }
}

I tried to build me schema like:
addNumberField($.subtable[*].subtime,1).as("subtime")

but off course this is for an array, not a hash.
Can someone point me to documentation of doing this thru a hash?
My query looks like:
Query().addFilter(new Query.NumericFilter("subtime",999998,999999)


TIA
Tried many things, and got pretty lost.
